# Is it appropriate to request internal recruiter provide feedback on resume before submission?

Tags: resume, recruitment

I am currently exploring the job market for a more senior role and have been working with a recruiter internal to the company I am targeting. I work in the Information Security profession.

**If after having edited and proofread my resume, would it be appropriate to ask the recruiter for feedback on it as to how it can be improved?**

Due to the depth of experience of having worked at the company, they may know something useful but privy to only insiders of that company. However I don't want to seem needy, incapable, or disrespectful of their time.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really work as a recruiter or in HR, but I have worked closely with the HR dept of my company. I have listened to them about their feedbacks regarding potential candidates, whether good or bad, why they are accepted, or why they are rejected.

People in HR may have different opinions to my answer, but you never know which answer is actually the spot-on help or is exactly what will happen in your situation.

My answer to your question is, the same with what will happen if you ask a teacher if your exam answers are correct **during** the exam, so you can edit your answers accordingly. Chances are the recruiter will question your professional experience, or whether you believe in yourself to be the candidate the company needs.

I suggest you search online about good resume examples to be more certain and confident about you own. For instance, there are many good professionals on LinkedIn who have posted their resume, or their profiles are their resumes.

So, in short, *I don't think it is the appropriate action you want to take in this situation.*

Comment: I agree, however, this doesn't exclude asking the recruiter wheter they need specific informations

Answer (score 1):

I recently applied for a job and although this was an external recruiter he came back quickly asking me to fill gaps in between jobs and what I was doing during that time (providing me with some examples) and order all my experience in chronological order with proper start and end dates.

If you have relevant experience your CV is most probably okay. If there are particular things the company expects to see the recruiter will let you know because they want you to get the job.

Answer (score 0):

> have been working with a recruiter internal to the company I am
>   targeting

Then it may already be too late. If not, there are various ways to get feedback on your CV:

- ask co-workers - although you may find that slightly invasive or embarrassing, and it might indicate that you are considering moving
- Submit it to an external recruiter; tell them that you are looking for a job, and would appreciate feedback on your CV ; they ought tot have seen enough to be able to help
- Pay one of those companies who keep spamming me who offer to review & rewrite your CV

That advise goes for everyone. In your case, if you are senior, then your CV is probably in good shape, since you landed jobs to get you this far, and you can Google for general advice. So unless your layout is a total disaster, I would expect experience to speak for itself. And, although your experience will be discussed at interview, your CV is only a means of landing the interview. Once you have done that, its layout, writing style, format, etc are of no import.

To (finally) answer your actual question. I do not think that you can ask for feedback, from a company to which you are applying, before interview.  And afterwards, what’s their motivation for doing so? You might get a quick email in response, so it can’t hurt. You *could* try asking HR in the final interview, when they ask if you have any questions. My advice is, for senior, don’t sweat the CV too much.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen cases where employees already working in the company have had their resume used to make the required/desired parts of the job posting. That way the company can make sure that the internal person they want to hire, can make it past the initial screening of the application/resume without a large number of other candidates able to pass the screen.

I have seen HR help employees, who are about to lose their job becasue of the end of a contract, improve their resume so they can successfully apply to internal or external positions. Though they don't, as far as i know, help you tweak a resume for a specific position. They tend to be generalist whose job is to help employees about to lose their coverage, they are not tasked with filling specific positions.

The only way I can see a recruiter within the hiring company helping somebody outside the company is if they were having trouble getting anybody to pass the initial screen. They could be tasked by the manager that will be supervising the new employee to reopen the posting, with a small change to the requirements, and then have them contact somebody who with a few small changes can pass the new screen. They really just need the outside person to reapply during the short window the new posting will be open.

But if they have many qualified candidates to interview they don't have a lot of incentive to help somebody else qualify. If they have one opening, and want to interview 10 people, and have 20 to pick from; they don't need 21.

Now a recruiter outside the company has different incentives; they can get paid by getting candidates past the initial screen. They can use your new resume multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Often times internal employees of a potential employer are not allowed to provide feedback on your Resume/CV, even if asked, as this could potentially open them to a lawsuit if you felt they were being discriminatory for any reason.  This is the unfortunate negative byproduct of [Equal Opportunity Employment laws found in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_employment_opportunity), but I assume this practice is followed in many other countries as well.